# Whats the best practice for writing custom exceptions to cater from a wide range of inputs?

Tags: python, exception

Whats the best practice for writing custom exceptions to cater from a wide range of inputs? I have an exception that can be raised sometimes with a range of inputs, and sometimes with none - and im unsure what the best approach is for handling this. I've handled it like this:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, status=None, message=None):
        self.status = status
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)
```

So this can be raised in two ways, with the custom elements and without:

```
raise CustomException(tool["status"], tool["message"])

raise CustomException
```

But i'm unsure if this is best practice or approach? It makes it easy to raise the exception with a range of cases but it looks messy to me. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What's messy about it? This is the normal template for the `__init__()` method of any class.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances under which you pass no arguments, you might consider defining two separate exceptions.